# I can't enable ip tables logging

Tags: debian, iptables

```
uname -a
Linux test 5.10.0-17-cloud-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.136-1 (2022-08-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux

# Install module
modprobe ipt_LOG

# Confirm the file _is_ there
cat /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_log/2
NONE

# Errors when trying to change this setting
echo ipt_LOG >/proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_log/2
bash: echo: write error: No such file or directory

sysctl net.netfilter.nf_log.2=nf_log_ipv4
sysctl: setting key "net.netfilter.nf_log.2": No such file or directory
```

I see nothing online about this error. Everything I see seems to say this should just work.

Answer (score 1):

Welp just figured this out. Needed to install another module:

`modprobe nf_log_ipv4`